# error of accessing interactive matplotlib from Jupyter Lab on GCP Linux

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipympl

I am running an example code to access ipympl from Jupyter Lab on GCP/Linux.
The code is at https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/blob/main/docs/examples/full-example.ipynb

```
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
"ipympl" in sys.modules
True

#Testing matplotlib interactions with a simple plot
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 20, 100)));

Error displaying widget: model not found
```

I have installed "ipympl". My env is :

```
3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41) 
[GCC 9.4.0]
ipympl version: 0.9.3
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.12.0
ipykernel        : 6.13.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.6
jupyter_client   : 8.2.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 2.5.0
jupyterlab       : 3.6.3
nbclient         : 0.7.4
nbconvert        : 7.3.1
nbformat         : 5.8.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.9.0
Known nbextensions:
config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
notebook section
  jupyter-matplotlib/extension  enabled 
  - Validating: OK
  jupyter_resource_usage/main  enabled 
  - Validating: OK
  nbdime/index  enabled 
  - Validating: OK
  jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
  - Validating: OK
tree section
  jupyter_server_proxy/tree  enabled 
  - Validating: OK
JupyterLab v3.6.3
/usr/local/share/jupyter/labextensions
    jupyterlab_pygments v0.2.2 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
    dask-labextension v6.1.0 enabled OK (python, dask_labextension)
    nbdime-jupyterlab v2.2.0 enabled OK
    jupyter-matplotlib v0.11.3 enabled OK
    jupyterlab-nvdashboard v0.8.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_nvdashboard)
    @jupyterlab/git v0.41.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab-git)
    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v5.0.7 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
    @jupyterhub/jupyter-server-proxy v4.0.0 enabled OK
    @jupyter-server/resource-usage v0.7.2 enabled OK (python, jupyter-resource-usage)
    @jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp v4.1.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab-lsp)
    @elyra/code-snippet-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/script-debugger-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/python-editor-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/metadata-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/pipeline-editor-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/code-viewer-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/theme-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/r-editor-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK
    @elyra/scala-editor-extension v3.15.0 enabled OK

Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
  app dir: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab


Disabled extensions:
    @jupyterlab/launcher-extension (all plugins)`
```

I have tested the same code on laptop and it worked well.
Please let me know if I missed anything ?